# MySQL Group Results by day using timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I need to take the following query and pull the total order counts and sum of the orders grouped by day.  I'm storing everything using timestamps.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as order_count,
    SUM(price + shipping_price) as order_sum,
    DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) as day
FROM `order`
WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where).'
```

I need to group by DAY but when I do for this past weekend's sales it takes my order_count and makes it 1 instead of 3.  How can I pull the above values grouped by day?

NOTE: The implode is used ONLY to define the time period (WHERE created >= TIMESTAMP AND <= TIMESTAMP)

**Update**

Without GROUP BY `day`

```
Array ( 
    [order_count] => 3
    [order_sum] => 69.70
    [day] => 17
)
```

With GROUP BY `day`

```
Array ( 
    [order_count] => 1
    [order_sum] => 24.90
    [day] => 17
)
```

I need this query to return each day that had sales, how many orders, and the sum of those sales.  I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here somewhere....

Comment: I beleive you will need to provide some data - it sounds perfectly normal that GROUP BY would return more rows and that aggregated functions will be reduced proportionally. So please provide something along the lines of sample input data, sample output data, expected output.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Are you just forgetting to add `GROUP BY ...` at the end?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as order_count,
    SUM(price + shipping_price) as order_sum,
    DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) as order_day
FROM `order`
WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where).'
GROUP BY order_day
```

### NOTE:

You cannot use `as day` for your day column because `day` is a MySQL function. Use something like `order_day`.

### Of Unicorns

Per @OMG Unicorn's comment, you can use:

```
DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) as `day`
```

So long as wrap `day` in **`** backticks.

Comment: Actually, you can use the name day, you just need backticks around it.  Unfortunately, SO uses backticks for code blocks, so I'm not sure how to show an example.

Comment: DAY gives the day of the month. For distinct days you should use `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))`

Comment: This is really old but wanted to say it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply use:

```
SELECT 
COUNT( id ) AS order_count, 
SUM( price + shipping_price ) AS order_sum
FROM  `order` 
GROUP BY LEFT( timestamp, 10 )
```

or even

GROUP BY SUBSTR( timestamp, 1, 10 )

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a naming conflict between `DAY()` (the function in MySQL) and `day` (your variable name).  Have you tried using something that wont conflict such as `order_day`?

Comment: I guess I didn't make the **NOTE** text big enough in my post.